# How can I carry out a reliable coordinate transformation for point data?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system

I have ArcGIS 10.0 with ArcGIS Server (AGS) 10.0. Due to a known bug in the AGS geometry service we cannot carry out coordinate transformations with AGS 10.0. Our Internet client therefore does not have a tool which converts point coordinates between out ETRS89 and the older( but still in use) Gauß-Kruger zone 3 System. A user asked me today to covert some coordinate pairs, and after doing it with arcgis I checked a couple of Online Services which claim to do the same thing. I found that a got 3 different results for the same coordinate pair!

My Test in ArcMap 10 was to simply click with the info Tool in the map projected in ETRS89 on an area in the aerial photo and read off the native coordinates. I then created a new data frame which had the same aerial photos transformed into Gauß-Kruger Zone 3 and clicked on the same point. The following readings were produced:

```
ArcGIS 

Gauß Kruger Zone 3 Dataframe
3570494.458
5877100.795

ETRS89 UTM Dataframe
570395.131  
5875189.237
```

I gave the Gauß-Kruger coordinates into the following 2 sites to see what they produced and got 2 different results.

[Berg- und Wanderportal](http://www.deine-berge.de/umrechner_koordinaten.php)

[The World Coordinate Converter](http://twcc.free.fr/)

Since I know that AGS Geomtry service transforms incorrectly, how should I test whether the coordinates are correct in ArcMap?

Comment: Just to confirm: did you set a transformation in ArcMap? (I think so) Each app may be using different transformations, so unless you can get confirmation on what's being used...

Comment: Yes. The Transformation method used was NTV2. The problem is not really with ArcMAP. I am really trying to understand why other online services get different results.

Comment: What is the datum in the first CRS? If it is different from ETRS89 then I am not surprised you get different results, you have a datum transformation.

Answer (score 1):

The quality of transformation is best with the ntv2 grid. I doubt that the other services use it; they might use a 7-parameter (or even 3-parameter) Helmert transformation instead. There was a bunch of transformation parameter sets used in Germany, every claimed to be "exact" in its area of definition. The ntv2 grid is a nationwide access to harmonize those calculations without gaps at the state borders.

On this page

http://www.crs-geo.eu/nn_124226/nsc_true/crseu/EN/CRS__Description/crs-national__node.html?__nnn=true

under `Germany -> DE_DHDN GK_3 -> Description of Transformation`, you can obtain official `verification data`. Try all services with it, and calculate the offset using a spread sheet.

If you don't trust Arcmap, you can use GDAL `cs2cs` commandline tool for the same transformations. It can also use NTV2 grids, if you specify it.